# How do I remove the only branch in a bare `git` repository?

Tags: git

I'm experimenting with some `githooks`, so I have setup a local bare repository with a symlink from `hooks` to the hooks stored elsewhere.

I have pushed the `master` branch to the `git` repo and, of course, the hook failed. :)

I want to reset the `git` repo to nothing, without deleting it and having to recreate the symlink etc.

**How do I delete the master branch, seeing as it is the only branch in the repository?**

```
$ git branch -d master
error: Cannot delete the branch 'master' which you are currently on.
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To remove the `master` ref, use `git update-ref -d refs/heads/master`.

#### Why shouldn't you `rm /refs/heads/master`?

`packed-refs` could exist, so `rm` sometimes doesn't work as expected.

BTW, what's the point to reset if you could just create a new empty repo instead? Just use `git init --bare repo.git`.

Comment: `rm refs/heads/master` is shorter than `git update-ref -d refs/heads/master`; why should I use the second?

Comment: @AlexChamberlain Because there is also `packed-refs` could exist, so `rm` sometimes doesn't work as expected. And yes, thanks about `refs/heads/` prefix, I've forgot about it.

Comment: `git init --bare repo.git` doesn't delete the branches currently there.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain I mean that instead of deleting everything from existing repo, you could just delete it and create a new pristine one.

Comment: Because I've setup a symlink for the hooks directory.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain symlink into the git's repo? Well, symlinks work good after target replaced. If symlinks from git's repo - then you could keep just `hooks` directory.

Comment: No, a symlink from hooks to somewhere else where I am developing the hooks.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you don't need to remove a branch, you'd use `git reset --hard REV` to set it to the desired new revision. However, if I understand yuo correctly, you want to reset it to "nothing", i.e. to the state as it was right after `git init` was first invoked. git doesn't seem to allow you to do that, but you can get a similar effect by simply removing `.git/heads/refs/master`. Here is a demonstration in a newly created repo:

```
[~/x]$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/author/x/.git/
[~/x]$ touch a      
[~/x]$ git add a
[~/x]$ git commit -m foo
[master (root-commit) 5fcc99c] foo
 0 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 a
[~/x]$ git log
commit 5fcc99cc396cf5bc2c2fa9edef475b0cc9311ede
Author: ...
Date:   Mon Sep 3 12:40:15 2012 +0200

    foo
```

Here you'd want to do this, but git doesn't allow it:

```
[~/x]$ git reset --hard HEAD^
fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD^': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions
```

However, you can do this instead:

```
[~/x]$ rm .git/refs/heads/master
```

Check that it worked by committing something

```
[~/x]$ touch b
[~/x]$ git add b
[~/x]$ git commit -m 'new history'
[master (root-commit) 0e692b9] new history
 0 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 a
 create mode 100644 b
[~/x]$ git log
commit 0e692b9bb77f526642dcdf86889ec15dfda12be0
Author: ...
Date:   Mon Sep 3 12:40:52 2012 +0200

    new history
[~/x]$ git branch 
* master
```

Comment: Removing the ref works for me. Of course, this doesn't remove the commits, but it serves the same purpose and the commits would be removed by a `git gc` if desired.

Comment: `rm` is a dirty solution, See my answer.